# Add and Subtract with Decimal Variable gives Different results in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

This last result should be zero , but sql gives it wrong

```
Declare @test as decimal(18,8) = 0
SET @test = @test + 0.000001375
SELECT @test --0.00000138
SET @test = @test - 0.000001375
SELECT @test --0.00000001 here it should be zero
```

Comment: Issue is, rounding occur at  adding process ,but in subtraction why not followed the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is to do with at what point rounding occurs here:

```
SET @test = @test - 0.000001375
```

If you inspect the plan XML, you will see this:

```
CONVERT_IMPLICIT(decimal(18,8),[@test]-(0.000001375),0)
```

The key thing to note as that the subtraction takes place **before** the conversion back to `DECIMAL(18, 8)`. SQL Server has [set rules for precision and scale](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) depending on the operation. When you add two decimals the scale of the result is defined as `Max(si, s2)` (where s1 is the scale of the first number and s2 is the scale of the 2nd). So since you are deducting a `DECIMAL(10, 9)` from a `DECIMAL(18, 8)`, your result will be `DECIMAL(20, 9)`.

At the point this is executed the value for `@test` is 0.00000138 (you appear to have already identified that as you have declared a decimal(18,8) but given a number with 9 decimal places that rounding will occur), so this expands to:

```
CONVERT_IMPLICIT(decimal(18,8),0.00000138-0.000001375,0)
```

Since the result is `DECIMAL(20, 9)` the extra decimal place is retained. So this becomes:

```
CONVERT_IMPLICIT(decimal(18,8),0.000000005,0)
```

Since rounding rules specify that this should round up, the value returned is 0.00000001, and not 0.

Answer (score 2):

You've declared decimal(18,8).
This 8 at the second param says to sql that your number has 8 decimal positions.
Change it to 9 to add the last '5' in you number 0.000001375.
Other way the sql will round your number to 0.00000138

Comment: I know I add and subtract value is of 9 decimal with original value of 8 digit , because that hard code value is pass as param in dapper query and value assign to it is 9 digit

Comment: Can you sanatize this extra decimal on your code? if the sql 8 positions is hard coded, than you've to work around it on your code, set some 'round rules' to ignore the last 9th position.